# Prevent to going back to severel activities, after one specific activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have something like a registration. It is about 4 to 5 activites.
And I want that the user is able to go back to every activity, until he closes
the last one - now all the activites should be 'finished' and the user 
gets to the main menu.

Example:

```
go from main menu up to activity 3:

main menu > 1 > 2 > 3 ; than go back to 2

main menu > 1 > 2 ;go to the last one 5;

main menu  >1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 ; now the user finishes the registration;

main menu
```

And if the user is now back to the main menu, I dont want him to get back to any of these
registration-activities.

I found a lot of equal questions, but the most are only about one activity.

Sorry for my bad english, it is not my mother tongue.

Thanks!

Ps: The answer from Rod works like a charm! I recommend for everyone with the same question to read the following article: [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 5th activity you should add the flag on the Intent that would clear all the top activities.. you can do it by:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```